# Laravel PHP overriding method with different parameters

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

Apologies if this has been asked many times before and if this is simply not doable in Laravel/PHP.

In my Laravel app I have a `PostController` which uses Laravel's resourceful naming conventions. I also have a `CommentController` that mostly replicates the `PostController` in every way and so I have decided that the `CommentController` should extend `PostController`.

The only difference so far is that the `store()` methods need to accept different `FormRequest` objects as they have different validation rules. So I have overridden the `store()` method to expect `CommentFormRequest` instead of `PostFormRequest` (both of which extend `FormRequest`).

This is kicking up an error that the overriding method parameters need to match the base method.

Is this expected? and is there a sensible solution to what I'm trying to do?

**Edited from here**

I'm just at the beginning of designing this project where users can create Posts, Questions, Polls, Adverts etc and they can Comment on any of these.

All of these are types of `Post`. Some have relationships with other Models e.g. a `Poll` might have a relationship to a `PredefinedAnswer` model where a generic `Post` might not.

Some might need different validation logic e.g. a user can decide if a generic `Post` is allowed comments, but maybe an `Advert` might never be allowed comments.

In my Database I was thinking these could all be stored is a `post` table but with a different `postable_type`.

In my Controllers I was thinking that most of the CRUD logic is the same between these different types. In some cases there might be differences that might need methods to be overridden.

So in my `PostController` I currently have a very simple `store()` method:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

    protected $postableType;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postableType = PostType::GENERIC;
    }

    public function store(PostStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $post = new Post();
        $post->message = $validated['message'];
        $post->user_id = $request->user()->id;

        $post->postable_type = $this->postableType;

        $post->save();

        return Redirect::route('feed');
    }
}
```

Say my `AdvertController` is identical logic but has different validation rules I was thinking:

```
class AdvertController extends PostController
{

    protected $postableType;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postableType = PostType::ADVERT;
    }

    public function store(AdvertStoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $advert= new Advert();
        $advert->message = $validated['message'];
        $advert->user_id = $request->user()->id;

        $advert->postable_type = $this->postableType;
        $advert->save();

        return Redirect::route('feed');
    }
```

Comment: instead create a common controller and abstract common method to that, the difference can remain in respective classes, also search about repository design pattern, makes me feel, your controllers are doing too many things.

Comment: Thanks @PrafullaKumarSahu for replying so fast! Of course, what a sensible approach.

I'll research as you suggest, but my controllers are only doing simple CRUD operations

Comment: Ideally (99% of the time) you will have NOT to override `store`, `index`, etc methods, if you are doing so, either is a bad design or you are doing something wrong. A controller should be doing unique stuff among its methods

Comment: hi @matiaslauriti thank you! Ah I see. So in this case where I have a `Post` a `Question` a `Poll` and a `Comment` etc. All of these have very similar logic and mostly the same attributes. Is it better to have completely separate controllers for each of these even with lots of code repetition? Or perhaps different Controllers with shared code in Traits? In my head, inheritance seemed the way to go, but grateful for the feedback!

Comment: Inheritance would not be the way in this case, but creating classes that would hold this logic. Depending on what it it is, it could be a trait, but ideally is going to be a bew class. You should share part of the code so we can see further

Comment: Thanks again! i've added more info to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hinting concrete implementations you'l get more bang for your buck out of hinting an *interface* instead, eg:

```php
interface StoreRequestInterface {
  public function validated(): RedirectResponse;
  public function user();
  // etc
}

class PostStoreRequest implements StoreRequestInterface {/* ... */}
class AdvertStoreRequest  implements StoreRequestInterface {/* ... */}

abstract class Controller {
    protected $postableType;

    public function store(StoreRequestInterface $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postableType = PostType::GENERIC;
    }
}

class AdvertController extends PostController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postableType = PostType::ADVERT;
    }
}
```

This way you:

- Don't have to re-define identical method bodies with slightly different parameter hints.
- Can call `parent::store($request)` in the case that a bit of special handling is required, eg: type/sanity checks, but the rest of the method is still the same.
- Can avoid the trap of defining "god" classes that vast swaths of your application classes have to trace their lineage to. You can define a standalone, drop-in replacement by simply implementing the expected interface.

You can likely go further and interface the other classes referenced here [eg: `ControllerInterface`, `RedirectInterface`, etc] and further simplify your code.